# In emacs on X, can I close frames on other displays?

Tags: linux, emacs, xorg

I'm at work, on a linux machine.  I ssh into machine alpha, with X forwarding.

```
tomfuture@work$ ssh -X alpha
```

Then I start up X-windows emacs.

```
tomfuture@alpha$ emacs
```

It shows up on my local display.  I do some work, and go home, leaving emacs running.  On my linux machine at home, I can ssh in to alpha, and open up a new emacs frame connected to the same emacs.

```
tomfuture@home$ ssh -X alpha
tomfuture@alpha$ emacsclient -c
```

I now have two emacs frames running, one at work and one at home, both connected to the same emacs, which is running on alpha.  From home, how can I:

1. close the frame running at work?  or
2. close emacs entirely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can close all other frames with function `delete-other-frames`, which is bound to <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>.  You can close Emacs entirely by typing <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> as usual.  It will terminate Emacs, thus closing all frames.

Comment: Both of these seem to only close frames on the display I'm on.  My goal is to close frames running on a different X-windows display.

Comment: Both?  If `C-x C-c` (which kills Emacs) leaves frames open on other displays, then those frames weren't drawn by the Emacs you are killing.  Is it possible you are running two Emacs?

Comment: `ps aux` lists only one emacs process.  `M-x describe-key C-x C-c` says that `C-x C-c` is bound to `save-buffers-kill-terminal`.  It describes this function as "Offer to save each buffer, then kill the current connection.  If the current frame has no client, kill Emacs itself."  I'm not sure what it means for a frame to have a client, but it doesn't seem like `C-x C-c` is meant to always kill emacs.

Comment: Try binding `C-x C-c` to `save-buffers-kill-emacs` by putting this code at the end of your `~/.emacs` startup file: `(define-key global-map (kbd "C-x C-c") 'save-buffers-kill-emacs)`. I suspect that function `save-buffers-kill-terminal` is causing the behavior you don't like.

Comment: `save-buffers-kill-emacs` does the job (after warning me that it's going to delete another connect, which is nice).  Thanks!